# How do I remove the white margins around my div tags?

Tags: html, css, margin

So I have been creating a very basic website with a `header`, `nav`, main container, and a `footer`. and I'm using the the `viewport` tag in my website.

My problem occurs when I set the `width` of the `div`s to `100%`.

Here is my code:

```css
#header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#nav {
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  min-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#section {
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 479px;
  float: left;
}
#section p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
#footer p {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Is there something I need to change to get rid of the white edges around the div, I have tried things to get rid of it but none of them seem to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your HTML code, please? It'll be easier to understand what you mean by "white edges".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`body`has a default `margin` across browsers so you need to reset that `margin`.

so add this

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about the white edges around the website then use

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```